# Use model information before migration

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to write a serializer in DRF which uses another before for a choicelist. However when I try to migrate (initially) I get an error because the serializer is trying to query for a table before it's created:

```
from api.models.stock import Stock
from rest_framework import serializers

class ChartSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    symbol = serializers.ChoiceField(
        choices=Stock.objects.values_list('symbol', flat=True))

    option = serializers.ChoiceField(
        choices=['sparkline', '1d', '1w', '1m', '6m', '1y', '2y'])
```

The error is:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "api_stock" does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT "api_stock"."symbol" FROM "api_stock"

How can I change this? Do I need to check if `Stock` has been created before maybe?

Comment: Temporary put the `choices=...` in comment (well change it to `choices=[]`), then migrate, and put it back. That being said, it is perhaps not the best way to do that anyway. Since here you run a query when the server *starts*. So if a new `Stock` is created, then it will not show up in the options, unless you restart the server.

Comment: Is the query only executed once? I thought it would execute every time the serializer is used

Comment: No, then you will need a `ModelChoiceField`, with a `queryset`. The behavior is different than that of a `ChoiceField`.

Comment: I'm using DRF not a form in django. I'm not sure if DRF has a `ModelChoiceField`

Comment: sorry, I mean `ModelField`: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#modelfield

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt look like its validating the input.

Comment: I'm also open to trying a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` but I have to get the `symbol` field from the validated data somehow

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by using a SlugRelatedField like this:

```
symbol = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
    queryset=Stock.objects.all(), slug_field='symbol')
```